# Specific expectation of non-negative random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, markov-chains, expected-value

Let $T$ a random variable of non-negative integers. Suppose that there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and there is $\alpha>0$ such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\mathbb{P}(T >kn) \le (1-\alpha)^k.$$
Prove that
$\mathbb{E}[T] \le \frac{n}{\alpha}$.

I tried to use the sum formula for expectation of nonnegative integer random variables
$$\mathbb{E}[T] = \sum_{i \ge 0}{\mathbb{P}(T > i)},$$
but I can't get a '$\le$' innequalty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall from real analysis that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-a)^k = \frac{1-a}{a}\quad \text{for}\quad 0<a\le1.$$
Consider the random variable $n^{-1} T$. We can split its expectation up as follows: $$E[n^{-1}T] = E[n^{-1} T\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{T\ge n\}}] + E[n^{-1} T\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{0\le T<n\}}].$$
Observe that $$E[n^{-1} T\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{0\le T< n\}}]\le 1\cdot P(0\le T<n) = 1 - P(T\ge n).$$ On the other hand, $S:=\lceil n^{-1} T\rceil\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{T\ge n\}}$ is a non-negative integer-valued random variable and $$n^{-1} T\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{0\le T< n\}}\le S.$$ By its definition, note that the following hold:

- $S>0$ if and only if $T\ge n$,
- $S>k$ if and only if $T>kn$ for $k=1,2,\dots$.

Therefore, using the expectation identity for non-negative integer-valued random variables,
\begin{align*}
E[S]&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(S>k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(S>k) = P(S>0) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(S>k)\\
&=P(T\ge n)+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(T>kn) \le P(T\ge n) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-a)^k\\&= P(T\ge n) + \frac{1-a}{a}.
\end{align*}
Combining the above three inequalities, we have
$$E[n^{-1}T] \le [1-P(T\ge n)] + P(T\ge n) + \frac{1-a}{a} = \frac{1}{a}.$$
Complete the proof by multiplying both sides of the above inequality by $n$.

Comment: Thanks!!! I forget to say that $\alpha \in [0,1]$. But, I got the idea!

Comment: No problem. We should add the $a=1$ case, although it is not hard. In this case, $P(T>n) = 0$, so $P(T\le n) = 1$. Therefore, $E[T] \le n P(T\le n) = n$, as desired.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta Actually, I believe the $a=1$ case is covered by my answer. (But certainly doesn't require that full argument, evidenced by the shorter solution in the comments.) For $a=0$, it implies that $P(T>x)=1$ for all $x>0$. Therefore, $E[T]\ge x\cdot P(T>x) = x$ for all $x>0$. This implies that $E[T]$ is unbounded, and we write $E[T]=\infty$. Although dividing by $0$ is undefined, if we formally set $\infty=1/0$, then the statement is true in the $a=0$ case as well.